# Testing Doze feature (Android 6.0 Marshmallow) in Genymotion

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, genymotion, android-doze

I've tried the commands from Google

```
adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
```

on both "PREVIEW - Google Nexus 6P - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560" and "PREVIEW - Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920" virtual devices from Genymotion but unfortunately cannot put anyone to idle mode. Always after second command I see `Stepped to: ACTIVE`.

Then trying

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

I see `Unable to go idle; not enabled`. This is strange because Genymotion states in release note (https://www.genymotion.com/#!/release-notes) for version 2.6.0, which I use, that "Doze now works properly."

Is there anyone who managed to use and test Doze in Genymotion? Should I use some other commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm part of the Genymotion team.

The release note is not correct and our patch for Doze feature has not been released on the preview. Sorry for this mistake.

We will soon release Marshmallow officially and it will include Doze feature. On this future release you will need to enable Doze manually, at each device startup, by running the following command:

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle enable
```

Then, all the usual commands will work perfectly:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
```

**UPDATE:** The release has been done, Doze is available now  on Genymotion devices.

Comment: This is a great news. When can we expect the new release?

Comment: @Perry: We released it a few minutes ago. You can get it now.

Comment: The emulator seems to get in doze mode, but I tested setting an alarm using setExact() method and it does wake the device up in doze mode. Is the team working on this?